# error when compiling with ruby motion

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

here I have a ruby project recouped motion
I start to follow the installation cocoaPods who know and spend the time to compile the application it tells me the following problem =>

```
Twitter/SHKiOS5Twitter.h: 10:9: fatal error: 'SHKSharer.h' file not found
# import "SHKSharer.h"
Facebook / SHKFacebook.h: 30:9: fatal error: 'SHKSharer.h' file not found
# import "SHKSharer.h"
Twitter / SHKTwitter.m: 31:9: fatal error: 'SHKConfiguration.h' file not found
# import "SHKConfiguration.h"
```

I do not understand why because I followed the instruction by

```
$ Sudo gem install cocoapods
$ Pod setup

$ Sudo gem install motion-cocoapods
```

thank you

Comment: We don't have nearly enough information to help you. What OS are you running? Where is your Ruby installed? Append the output of `gem env` to your question.

Comment: Rubymotion runs on OSX. But as the Tin Man said above, this is not nearly enough information to hope to get a response here.

Comment: my operating system is an OS X 10.8.4 (12E55) and my ruby version is: ruby ​​2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0] but I've made ​​a small program with rubymotion who walked well,
but I think I cocaopods not install all or I should add the missing classes to twitter and facebook.

Comment: In the future, please add the necessary information to the question itself.  You can use the _edit_ link to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you need to [modify your Rakefile](https://github.com/HipByte/motion-cocoapods#setup):

Below `$:.unshift("/Library/RubyMotion/lib")`, add:

> ```
> require 'rubygems'
> require 'motion-cocoapods'
> ```

and then :

> ```
> Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|
>   # ...
>   app.pods do
>     pod 'JSONKit' #Name of your pod
>   end
> end
> ```